# JXL library in Android

Tags: java, android, excel, jxl

Currently i am trying to use Jxl lib in android to read data from sd card and getting FilenotfoudException.

I have used stackoverflow to search for solutions and found some. but non of them seems to be working for me. I have following code implemented :
    /*Code section*/

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
//Get the text file
File Excelfile = new File(sdcard,"ExcelTest.xls");
//
try {
    Workbook wrkbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(Excelfile);
    Sheet sheet1 = wrkbk.getSheet(0);
    //Obtain reference to the Cell using getCell(int col, int row) method of sheet
    Cell colArow1 = sheet1.getCell(0, 0);
    Cell colBrow1 = sheet1.getCell(1, 0);
    Cell colArow2 = sheet1.getCell(0, 1);
    //Read the contents of the Cell using getContents() method, which will return
    //it as a String
    String str_colArow1 = colArow1.getContents();
    String str_colBrow1 = colBrow1.getContents();
    String str_colArow2 = colArow2.getContents();
    }
Catch(Exception ex){}
```

I am always getting exception at line   Workbook wrkbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(Excelfile);

I have searched for solution but nothing seems to work. I have provided all permissions for reading files on sd card(have checked it by reading a text file and it works fine).

Same code works in normal java program.

Please help.....

Answer (score 2):

It's probably late for answer, but your actual file might be somewhere in a folder. Therefore, you have to get the full path. In your case, it is

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File Excelfile = new File(sdcard,"/folder_name/ExcelTest.xls");
```

Hope this will help.